# hide unhide layers in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers

I want to hide some layers when I click in a layer and restore the visibility back after clicking out. I tried with this code but it doesn't work - here is also the plunker code - [Hide show layers](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHB4iuf6aZAOTE79idET?p=preview)

```
var layerVisibility = {};

var piky2 = new L.geoJson(pol01).addTo(map);
var piky3 = new L.geoJson(pick1).addTo(map);
var piky4 = new L.geoJson(pick2).addTo(map);

var piky1 = new L.geoJson(pol00, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      fillOpacity: 0.55,
      weight: 7,
      color: '#eff682'
    };
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      'mousemove': function(e) {
        e.target.setStyle({
          weight: 7,
          color: 'red'
        });
      },
      'mouseout': function(e) {
        //reset hiden layer to be shown
        layerVisibility[L.Util.stamp(pol01)] = true;
        piky1.resetStyle(e.target);
      },
      'click': function(e) {
        piky1.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name);
        //Hide some layers 
        layerVisibility[L.Util.stamp(pol01)] = false;
      }
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide a feature you can give it an invisible color with `rgba(0,0,0,0)` (the last value is the transparency value, 1.0 = opaque, 0 = fully transparent).

```
var piky1=new L.geoJson(pol00,{
    style: function (feature) {
        return {
            fillOpacity: 0.55,
            weight: 7,
            color: '#eff682'
        };
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            'click': function (e) {
                e.target.setStyle({
                    weight: 7,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                });
            }
        });
    }}).addTo(map);
```

Making a feature visible again if a user clicks *outside* of it is a bit trickier since there's no [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/blur) event on Leaflet's layers. What you can do is listen for clicks on the `map` and reset all features then:

```
map.on('click', function(e){
  piky1.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    piky1.resetStyle(layer);
  });
});
```

Hiding individual markers it not currently supported, but should be coming in the future version 1.0 (see [bug report](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4)). You can hide a marker's icon by providing an invisible icon with `setIcon()`, but you can not use `setIcon()` on `eachLayer()`. Instead, you can use Javascript `.style` properties (similar to CSS properties) on the icon to hide or show it.

```
// hide marker on click
layer.on('click', function(m){
    m.target._icon.style.display = 'none';
    m.target._shadow.style.display = 'none';
});

// show all markers again
piky3.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer._icon.style.display = 'block';
    layer._shadow.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/rj1eF0ZhEpDGnwkz4oZr?p=preview

Comment: but the color tricks don't work for markers?

Comment: thanks . I found also the  map.removeLayer(layer); &  map.addLayer(layer); easy to use methode.

Comment: I added my previous comment to the post. Yes add/removeLayer works too